# How to show single quotes in string in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am generation dynamic content using javascript and inside that content a part will be like

```
onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Email Address'){this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value=='')    {this.value='Enter Email Address';}" value="Enter Email Address"
```

I want above code but after generation of the content but all the single quotes are not showing properly. Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Change `;}\"` to `;}"`

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in HTML 5 with input element, i would suggest you to look at the `placeholder` attribute, as this is exactly what you are needing for. No javascript needed.

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email Address" />
```

Comment: Placeholder is not supported by all the browsers

Answer (score 0):

use Escape character \

```
'\\'Enter Email\\''
```

Comment: But it can be `'\\'Enter Email\\''`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
'\'Text\''
```

or

```
"'Text'"
```

Comment: when I write \'Text\' its convert into "Text"

Answer (score 0):

try something like this , Remove backslash from double quotes,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yVxLe/)

```
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Email Address'){this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value=='')    {this.value='Enter Email Address';}" value="Enter Email Address">
```